# store results in jList and in arraylist

Tags: java, resultset

I execute my sql query with recordset and I would like to show results in a jList and store in array list but it is not working, i want to store only 2 registers. This is my code:

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

while (rs.next()) {
    listModel.addElement(rs.getObject(1));
    resultadoArray.add(rs.getObject(1).toString());
}
```

Could you help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your ResultSet fetches only 2 results. Did you check that?

Comment: Yes, If I remove arraylist add it shows me a lot of results

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `rs.getObject()` does something funny the second time. Therefore do it only once:

```java
while (rs.next()) {
    Object object=rs.getObject(1);
    listModel.addElement(object);
    resultadoArray.add(object.toString());
}
```

Comment: Not works, onlye one result. However, if I comment resultadoArray line works ok filling JList

Comment: Then maybe an error at ``object.toString()`` occurs that you don't catch?

Comment: strange because these column database is varchar

Comment: I suggest you do some debugging to investigate this.